# Invisible bits in node-gyp error messages running Konsole under VMware

Tags: kde, vmware, konsole, kde5

With node-gyp's colored error messages*, some bits end up invisible in Konsole:

[image: invisible bits in Konsole]

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, running under VMware Workstation with 3D acceleration enabled. If I copy/paste the text from Konsole to somewhere else, the invisible bits are revealed, which suggests this is a rendering issue.

Note that the glitched bits stay black even when selected, and end up looking like redaction bars:

[image: glitched bits selected]

* I believe node-gyp is running GCC behind the scenes, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: As a temporary solution I can set `TERM=dumb` to disable color-coded messages, but it would be nicer to be able to use color coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a "rendering issue", but equally likely with Konsole is that its color palette happens to be something that makes it hard to see, e.g., if someone **assumed** that the background of the terminal is a light color and is printing black text on that.  You can see if this is the case by changing your terminal's color palette.

Comment: Oh wow, you're exactly right! I've had problems with VMs, 3D acceleration, and KDE5 before, so I assumed that this was something similar--but actually, it turns out my color scheme is messed up. Thanks! I'll accept your answer as soon as Stack Exchange allows me to.